# Spring boot: Deleting an entity in a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-boot, many-to-many

I am working on a spring boot library application with mysql,jpa. It has 2 entities book, person. Each person can take more than one book and each book can be taken by more than one person (depending on the book copies available).
Here is how I approached this,

**Book.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="book")
public class Book {

    /*@Id
    @Column(name="bookId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int bookId;*/

    @Id
    @Column(name="bookName")
    private String bookName;

    @Column(name="author")
    private String author;

    @Column(name="copiesTotal")
    private int    copiesTotal;

    @Column(name="copiesAvailable")
    private int    copiesAvailable;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="listOfBooks", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Person> listOfPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public Book() {

    }

    public Book(String bookName, String author, int copiesTotal, int copiesAvailable) {
        super();
        //this.bookId = bookId;
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.author = author;
        this.copiesTotal = copiesTotal;
        this.copiesAvailable = copiesAvailable;
        //this.people = people;

    }
//followed by getters and setters
```

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Column(name="personId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int personId;

    @Column(name="personName")
    private String personName;

    @Column(name="mobile")
    private String mobile;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="book2persons",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="personId"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="bookName"))
    private List<Book> listOfBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public Person() {

    }

    public Person(int personId, String personName, String mobile) {
        super();
        this.personId = personId;
        this.personName = personName;
        this.mobile = mobile;

    }
```

When a person borrows a book, he selects an existing book from dropdown,enters his name,mobile and borrows the book.

**BookController.java** //only showing some part of the code here

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String borrowBook(@ModelAttribute Book book, @ModelAttribute Person person) {
        String bookToBorrow = book.getBookName();
        String personToBorrow = person.getPersonName();
        String mobile = person.getMobile();
        Book dbBook = bookService.getBook(bookToBorrow);

        if(dbBook.getCopiesAvailable() >= 1) {
            List<Book> listOfBooks = Arrays.asList(dbBook);
            List<Person> listOfPersons = Arrays.asList(person);
            person.setListOfBooks(listOfBooks);
            book.setListOfPersons(listOfPersons);
            dbBook.setCopiesAvailable(dbBook.getCopiesAvailable() - 1);
            personService.borrowedBy(person);
            //bookService.decreaseCopiesAvailable(dbBook);
            bookService.updateBook(dbBook);
            return "borrowed_details";
        }
        else {
            return "book_not_available";
        }


    }
```

**Question1**  is when a person returns a book, I am unable to find a way to update it in database. How to delete the row related to person and that book?

**Question2** Is the approach (manytomany,jointable) correct to create this application or is it better to create it in the following manner without manytomany relation,
1. Create table Book: bookName(primarykey),author,copiesTotal,copiesAvailable
2. Create table Person: personId(autogenerated pk),personName,bookName,mobile 
3. When a person borrows, he is added to Person table with bookName; If he borrows another book,one more row is added with that bookName
4. When a person returns book,the row is deleted with personName and bookName query
I feel this approach is easier. Am I missing some drawbacks?
Thanks you!

Comment: Your question 2 approach is better, also instead of deleting the row add one more field like book_returned which can be true or false

Comment: @AkhilMenon Thank you!!!

Comment: Regarding question #1, returning a book is trivial: simply remove the `Book` from `Person.listOfBooks`. I'm assuming here that `borrowBook` is transactional (it really should be - in fact, I'd strongly advise that you refactor your code to extract the entire logic into a transactional service layer method. Even though your app seems to have a service layer, some business logic is still performed in the controller method, which smells of poor separation of concerns)

Comment: @crizzis Yeah, I am confused with some code i.e. whether to put it in controller or service layer. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

I find approach 2 worse because:

1. you can only register a person when they borrow a book.
2. you are going to have to duplicate that person and all his
       personal information everytime he borrows a book

approach one is fine but
 since you might want to have additional information on the `JoinTable` like
   when a user borrowed a book or if he returned or not, you would find easier to 
   create another entity for the joinTable instead of using ManyToMany

So that you end up with both `Book` and `User` entity with a `OneToMany` relation to a `UserBook` entity

You can follow this example https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/